# Get hold of a Listener loaded the Spring context

Tags: java, spring, akka

I have a web application that loads a Spring context in the standard way:

web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
             org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Unfortunately my application is not a "pure" web application, meaning that I don't have a real front end but just Akka remote actors that get initialized via a web.xml Listener as well.
My Akka actors (standard POJOs) needs to get hold of the Spring context, so my question is: how do I get hold of the Spring context from a class that has no reference to the Servlet context?

Basically I cannot use:

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ctx);
```

...because Akka actors have no reference to the ServletContext.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do the actors need access to the spring context?

Comment: I'm using Typed Actor that use some services. The actors don't really need to get hold of the Spring context, they just need dependency to be injected. I have played a bit with the Sprink/Akka integration but had some issues with the latest code release, maybe I should investigate more.
Anyway, my Actors need some services, so at the moment - having no injection - I have to use the context.getBean(..) approach from inside the Actor. Not optimal, but I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own Initializer that will create an instance of a SpringContextActor with a well known id, and then the actors needing to do something with the SpringContext can look the SpringContextActor in the ActorRegistry and send messages to it.

Comment: Great, thanks for the idea. I have implemented a SpringContextActor that is initialized at boot time and is dispatching bean like anything!

Answer (score 1):

- If these POJOs are spring beans, you can make them implement `ApplicationContextAware`
- You can use `@Configurable` to make any pojo a spring bean
- If they are not spring beans, you can store the `ServletContext` in JNDI on startup, and access it via JNDI.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wonder about a design that depended so strongly on the web tier.

The recommended Spring idiom is to have a POJO interface service layer that's called from the web tier.  The benefit is that the service layer can be used even if the web tier is completely removed.

If you don't have a service layer, perhaps adding one would give you the flexibility to use it without the web tier or app server.

Comment: Actually, is a bit more complicated than that. I do have a 3 tier design, problem is that the front tier is actually an Akka actor. The actor calls into a business layer that finally uses a Dao layer. Pretty basic design.
I can always initialize the spring context from the Actor itself but I thought that it was more elegant to initialize the context in the Listener, considering that my Akka actors are initialized by a specific Listener anyway.

Comment: But now they're coupled with the web tier.  It's not to say that you shouldn't initialize them with the Listener when you have a web tier.  You just want to design it so you can detach the web tier when needed (e.g., for unit testing).  If you can't test without the web tier, you need to figure out how.